# Is there any historical mention of Richard Feynman being aware of multiverse theories of cosmology?

Tags: biographical-details, physicists, cosmology, feynman

The reason I ask is because he talks about the fine structure constant in one of his undergraduate  lectures.

The reference to its mystery is analogous to all the special constants of nature such as the cosmological constant and so on and so forth that are attempted to be explained by either the anthropic principle or invoking multiverses

It seems to work in today's physics and I am curious why Feynman didn't use this argument.  Not that I am saying it is an explanation but I am sure he would have had something to say about it.

I am not really sure what tags I should even use for this question.

Comment: I don't know what the many worlds interpretation has to do with mathematical coincidences/deductions of various fundamental constants (I assume you mean [Eddington's speculations on this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Eddington#Fundamental_theory_and_the_Eddington_number)), but Feynman was certainly aware of the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, as it was well known in the 1960s -- 1980s. In fact, [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/069161895X) was prominently displayed in my undergraduate university's bookstore throughout when I was a student there, 1977-1981

Comment: On re-reading your question, it seems that you're actually not talking about the stuff Eddington is well known for (in his later years), but rather issues related to how finely tuned the structure of the universe is, and our existence is, relative to things like the fine structure constant. Certainly Feynman would have known about this, as it too was widely discussed and written about during the last few decades of Feynman's life. Paul Davis wrote about this in many of his late 1970s and 1980s books, for example.

Comment: These links are certainly interesting ......I was thinking along the line of the "many landscapes" of string theory and multiple universes but my intent was to get a sense of what he felt about speculations of "multiple" universes in general .